# Sum data from one table if date range is in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I have two query results like this:

[image]

[image: table 2]

I would like to use this 2 queries and then SUM the Seconds of the second table (Mains - Charging) if that specific device (43 in this case) was connected in the date range of the first table for that period using the left and right date limits. So SUM only if that condition is met.

Any suggestion on how I can accomplish this ?

This is the table script and some sample data:

First table script:

```
CREATE TABLE firstTable(
   DeviceId     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Date         DATE  NOT NULL
  ,DisplayValue VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,LeftLimit    DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,RigthLimit   DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,Seconds      INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 00:00:00.000','2017-06-27 10:17:54.460',37074);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:54.460','2017-06-27 10:17:56.293',2);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:56.293','2017-06-27 10:17:56.330',0);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:56.330','2017-06-27 10:17:57.430',1);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:57.430','2017-06-27 10:17:57.440',0);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:57.440','2017-06-27 10:17:58.637',1);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:58.637','2017-06-27 10:17:58.783',0);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:58.783','2017-06-27 10:17:59.657',1);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:59.657','2017-06-27 10:17:59.903',0);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:17:59.903','2017-06-27 10:18:00.977',1);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:18:00.977','2017-06-27 10:18:01.027',1);
INSERT INTO firstTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Connected','2017-06-27 10:18:01.027','2017-06-27 10:18:01.517',0);
```

Second table script:

```
    CREATE TABLE secondTable(
   DeviceId     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Date         DATE  NOT NULL
  ,DisplayValue VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,LeftLimit    DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,RigthLimit   DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,Seconds      INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO secondTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Mains - Charging','2017-06-27 00:00:00.000','2017-06-27 10:17:57.523',37077);
INSERT INTO secondTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Mains - Charging','2017-06-27 10:17:57.523','2017-06-27 10:17:59.883',2);
INSERT INTO secondTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Mains - Charging','2017-06-27 10:17:59.883','2017-06-27 10:17:59.953',0);
INSERT INTO secondTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Mains - Charging','2017-06-27 10:17:59.953','2017-06-27 10:18:01.043',2);
INSERT INTO secondTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Mains - Charging','2017-06-27 10:18:01.043','2017-06-27 10:18:01.103',0);
INSERT INTO secondTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Mains - Charging','2017-06-27 10:18:01.103','2017-06-27 10:18:01.553',0);
INSERT INTO secondTable(DeviceId,Date,DisplayValue,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,Seconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27','Mains - Charging','2017-06-27 10:18:01.553','2017-06-27 10:18:01.630',0);
```

Expected Result:

```
CREATE TABLE expectedResult(
   DeviceId     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LeftLimit    DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,RigthLimit   DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,TotalSeconds INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO expectedResult(DeviceId,LeftLimit,RigthLimit,TotalSeconds) VALUES (43,'2017-06-27 00:00:00.000','2017-06-27 10:18:02.630',37081);
```

Expected Result table:

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| DeviceId |        LeftLimit        |       RightLimit        | TotalSeconds |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
|       43 | 2017-06-27 00:00:00.000 | 2017-06-27 10:18:02.630 |        37081 |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: In a word...huh???

Comment: @SeanLange IE: for example because from 00:00 to 10:18:01:517 device 43 was "Connected" I want to sum "Seconds" from second table if the interval of time is between an interval of the first table. So I will sum record 1,2,3,4,5,6 from the second table.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Here is a great place to start improving this question. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange.I have updated the description. Hope its clearer now.

Comment: You might try testing your code before you post it. Your inserts all point to the same table. And fixing that causes primary key violations because you are insert 43 over and over. Does that mean the foreign key is incorrect or your sample data is invalid? I am still pretty fuzzy on your requirements here.

Comment: @SeanLange fixed the sample data. Please look at the expected output TotalSeconds.

Comment: OK now we have sample data. Can you try to explain the logic? You talk about time intervals but I don't get what you want. Why does only the earliest row from firsttable appear in the output? What about the other rows in that table for that device?

Comment: The output does not contain the first row of the first table.
If you notice the output is the SUM of the second table rows and the date limits are the LeftLimit of the first row and the RightLimit of the last row.
Because the device was "Connected" on that interval as you can check in the first table data.
If the device was not connected I would not want to SUM the seconds and that is why I need the first table.

Comment: Right...but look at the time in your output. Which row does that come from? You have 12 rows in firstTable and 7 in secondTable. Why does it display the earliest value? Does it have to be connected the entire interval? Some significant portion of it? Seriously I am trying to help but I can't read your mind here and don't know what you want.

Comment: I am trying to explain as well... If you look at the first table you can see that device 43 was connected from 2017-06-27 00:00:00.000  2017-06-27 10:18:01.517 all those 12 rows are consecutive. So I want to sum everything from the second table that contains intervals that are inside of this one. In this specific case I need to SUM the first 5 rows of the second table cause the intervals fit inside of this. 2017-06-27 00:00:00.000 to 2017-06-27 10:18:01.103 . TotalSeconds = 37077+2+0+2+0=37081.

Comment: Ahh gotcha...the basic islands and gaps problem. What you need is handy way to groups islands of contiguous dates and this challenge becomes quite simple. Thankfully Jeff Moden has an excellent article on this very topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Comment: Hello @SeanLange the link you shared is used to create ranges using single datetimes. What I need is different. Cant see this working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 ST.[DeviceId],
 MIN(CASE WHEN FT.[LeftLimit] > ST.[LeftLimit] THEN FT.[LeftLimit] ELSE ST.[LeftLimit] END) AS [LeftLimit],
 MAX(CASE WHEN FT.[RigthLimit] < ST.[RigthLimit] THEN FT.[RigthLimit] ELSE ST.[RigthLimit] END) AS [RigthLimit],
 SUM(DATEDIFF(
  SECOND,
  CASE WHEN FT.[LeftLimit] > ST.[LeftLimit] THEN FT.[LeftLimit] ELSE ST.[LeftLimit] END,
  CASE WHEN FT.[RigthLimit] < ST.[RigthLimit] THEN FT.[RigthLimit] ELSE ST.[RigthLimit] END)) AS [TotalSeconds]
FROM firstTable FT
INNER JOIN secondTable ST ON ST.[DeviceId] = FT.[DeviceId] AND (FT.[LeftLimit] <= ST.[RigthLimit] AND ST.[LeftLimit] <= FT.[RigthLimit])
GROUP BY ST.[DeviceId]
```

Join the first table on the second, but only where the date ranges overlap. Then take the min left and max right limit and sum.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN the two tables ON the `LeftLimit` from the 2nd table being greater than the MIN `LeftLimit` from the 1st table, AND the `RightLimit` from the 2nd table being less than the MAX `RightLimit` from the 1st table.   And also on `DeviceId` of course.

You'll also need to CAST all your limit columns as datetimes so that they compare correctly.

Comment: You cannot have aggregates in an ON clause. Also I think this will not output the expected result.